# How to delete hdfs files from last month?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to delete hdfs files from last month.
It doesn't matter if it deleted to trash or deleted permanently.

Maybe regex can assist here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer that helped me with this question using regex:

hadoop fs -rm -R -skipTrash /folderA/folderB/[0-9][0-9]82016*

This way I will delete all folders and their content from August 2016.
Without -R I will skip recursive deletion.
-skipTrash will delete the files permanently.